# Google maps API v2 to v3 directions/info panel

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-android-api-2

how can I get something like this on gmaps v3 api?

https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m8!1m3!1d183936.18701586724!2d15.498622262704465!3d43.917913576992646!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x0%3A0x6e7b774ca6e9b29a!2sPine+Beach+Pako%C5%A1tane!5e0!3m2!1shr!2shr!4v1394620132966

so the problem I'm having is that I cannot get the top left panel there? With the info, directions and that stuff.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do something like this [save-widget](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/save-widget) does, and add some control option in the HTML code.